# Drupal 7 - Term reference field: how to add new term?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, entityreference

I have some texonomies in my Drupal website. Some of them have additional fields. I have some fields of type **Term reference** in my content-types.

When I am creating a new node of a content-type, I would like to have the ability to add a new term to the taxonomy while I'm filling the form of the Content-Type (with an "add item" link/popup...).

I can do that if I use **Entity Reference** fields, but I cannot using **Term reference** field. Could you help me, please?

Thanks

UPDATE: I installed "Taxonomy access fix" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix) and it allows me to set capabilities per each taxonomy based on user role. Now I only need to add a new term to a Taxonomy on a form level using Term reference field (I canno use autocomplete because I need the user to see all possible values like with a dropdown).

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

If you change your widget to the autocomplete widget, it will let you add new values.

Comment: yeah thanks! I also need the user to see the list of all the avalaible values (like in a dropdown). any suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Dark FlameS, in fact we are using the autocomplete widget for some of our students to add types of trees in the biology lab and they tag each with the scientific name. 
And since we dont know these scientific terms, we let them add taxonomy terms to the list. 
**Slight difference however, we use the module [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe). Works like magic for us.**

You are able to see what taxonomy terms are already available by clicking into the text area.

And as you type a taxonomy term, you will see what other terms are similar. If a tag is new, it will be added. one thing, dont allow them to delete your tags. We learned this the hard way.

See the image below on what it looks like as you add a tag. 
[image]
Above is what you will see when you are adding the taxonomy field in your content type, this is after you install the Autocomplete Deluxe module

[image]

Above is What the user sees when they add or select a taxonomy tag.